# Rails 5 has_many association with reusable model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been working on this problem for a while and I think my lack of Rails database design is getting the best of me.

I'm building a site for a client that offers party services for four(4) locations in Southern California.

For this, I have three(3) models - `Locations, Categories, Products`.

For example:

```
http://somewebsite.com/san-diego/birthday-parties/boy-themed
http://somewebsite.com/orange-county/birthday-parties/boy-themed
http://somewebsite.com/los-angeles/birthday-parties/boy-themed
http://somewebsite.com/riverside/birthday-parties/boy-themed
```

The only model that is unique because it has a different price and description for each location is the Product model. The Location model has many Categories and the Category model has many Products. I have everything working except when I create a new Category, I can't select multiple locations, I have to re-create the same Category name 4 times; one for each location.

Here is my code.

**schema**

```
  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "location_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_categories_on_location_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
  end
```

**models**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
...

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  has_many :products
...

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
...
```

**category controller**

```
<%= form_for([@location, @category]) do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name, id: :category_name, class: 'input-md input-square form-control'  %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :location_id, 'Parent Location' %>
      <%= form.select :location_id, Location.order(:name).collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, { multiple: true, include_blank: true } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'button button-pasific' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I see one error in your code. In category model. I think it should be `belong_to :locations`

Comment: @Maxence a model never belongs to a plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a series of join tables to create many-to-many associations instead:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :location_categories
  has_many :locations, through: :location_categories
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :location_categories
  has_many :locations, through: :location_categories
end

class LocationCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This allows any category to have multiple locations and vice versa.

Another way to define this which avoids duplication would be get categories indirectly through products:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product 
  belongs_to :category
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :categories, through: :products
end
```

Your schema so far is very naive and you might want to go back to drawing it up on a peice of paper and think about what sort of objects you need and what the associations between them are. As long as its not a direct one-to-one or one-to-many you need to provision joins.

- [The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: You also might want to create a "normalized" products table and a localized table which contains the price etc.